# Why is the .equals() method not overriden for arrays of primitives in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, equals, language-design

I am currently working on a project where I want to implement a login mechanism using a username and a password that gets compared against a database.

I had something like this in mind:

```
public boolean verifyUser( String username, char[] password ) 
{
  List<char[]> dbpass = getPasswords( username );
  if ( dbpass.contains( password ) )
  {
    overwriteWithNonsense( password );
    return true;
  }
  overwriteWithNonsense( password );
  return false;
}
```

when I noticed that my unit tests were failing. So I took a deeper look at it an noticed that the `Object::equals` method is not overriden for arrays of primitives which explained why `List::contains` would **always** evaluate to `false`.

I know there is a possible workaround using:

```
if ( dbpass.stream().anyMatch( pw -> Arrays.equals( pw, password ) ) )
{
  overwriteWithNonsense( password );
  return true;
}
```

My question is why the designer chose to keep the 'default implementation' of `Object::equals`? Wouldn't it be way more convenient than implementing a framework with static utility methods like `Arrays.equals(array1,array2)`?

Comment: Equals isn't overridden for arrays at all. So it isn't overridden for arrays of objects either.

Comment: You can say "arrays of primitives". But I guess in Java there isn't such a class.

Comment: If, as is common practice, you're overwriting passwords to hide from a debugger or memory dumy, then you also need to overwrite the ones you fetched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any `Collection`s of `array`s is mostly bad design. They should not be used together. You're probably better of by introducing a trivial, but needed `class`:

```
public class Password{
     private final char[] password;

     public Password(char[] password){
         this.password = password;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object obj){
         // equals logic
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode(){
         // hashCode logic
     }
}
```

And then having a `List<Password>`. (I also shortened your `verifyUser` method because it seemed a bit redundant):

```
public boolean verifyUser( String username, char[] password ){
    List<Password> dbpass = getPasswords(username);
    boolean contained = dbpass.contains(new Password(password));
    overwriteWithNonsense(password);
    return contained;
}
```

---

(Your other question regarding the *why* it is not overriden is mostly off-topic, because only the java-devs could really answer that.)

Comment: Your approach is similar to what i had in mind when thinking of a workaround an I approve. It is a lightweight way to handle such issues. And I don't think it is to far off-topic because there might by many people out there who were not the language designer and still have a much deeper understanding about the design process as such and have a proper explanation. SO doesn't always have to be about solving issues like: "I don't know how to code xyz to achiev abc" in my opinion.

Comment: @L.Spillner That wasn't my point. Just the question *why the designer chose to keep the 'default implementation'* is directly pointed at the *designer*, so the Java-developpers. That's why it's off-topic. Because Brian Goetz may not always be around answering questions like yours ;)

Comment: To further back @Lino, for any none-light use of Java arrays, you almost certainly want to encapsulate it into a class.  Not only that you can add methods like `hashCode()` and `equals()`, but also you can make it immutable, which brightens up the entire world.  The Java String class is a perfect example.  But in your case (handling password), I understand the choice of a char array over String. Just wrap it into your own class.

Answer (score 4):

In Java `array` is not a class but from [Java Doc section 4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) it is treated as an object. Now as this is not a class there's no code for `equals/hashCode`.

Now, for your solution to compare arrays you can use `Arrays.equals` method to compare two arrays:

```
public boolean verifyUser( String username, char[] password ) 
{
    List<char[]> dbpass = getPasswords( username );
    for(char[] arr : dbpass)
    {
        if ( Arrays.equals(arr,password) )
        {
            overwriteWithNonsense( password );
            return true;
        }
    }

    overwriteWithNonsense( password );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The link to the definition clearly sorted a few aspects of my initial question +1. And thank you for your input on the workaround approach but I think I'll stick to mine because it's basically yours packed into a neat little stream :p

Comment: It's not correct that they're not classes.  Arrays are classes, they're just not compiled from Java source code, but instead are generated by the VM.  They can implement interfaces and methods; arrays implement Serializable and Cloneable, for example.  The lack of a source representation is not why they don't override equals and hashCode.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Looks logical but could you pls share documentation link from `Sun/ Oracle` for the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good reason. You're generally encouraged to use `ArrayList` as its a fully-fledged container. But there seems only good to be had by implementing `equals()` as per `AbstractList`. 
There's always `==` to determine if two references are the same object.

Java arrays are a bit of an unusual beast in that they might contain primitives but that doesn't seem too much of a hurdle.

Are these arrays equal?

```
Integer objects[]={Integer.valueOf(1),Integer.valueOf(1000)};
int integers[]={1,1000};
```

I'd go with 'no' as most consistent. But if not you will get the potentially surprise semantics that these objects won't be equal:

```
int ai[]={1,2,3}; 
long al[]={1,2,3};
```

Perhaps no one really thought about it and changing something so basic like that will surely have some code-breaking consequences.

Comment: General advice: when you think "I don't think there is a good reason", delete that thought and replace it with "There might be a good reason, but I don't know what it is."

Comment: @BrianGoetz Unless having throught through the possible impact of doing so you come up with no good reason. When do we move from thinking there might be a good reason to thinking there isn't? Shall we go to the beach today? "There might be a good reason, but I don't know what it is." Do you like the beach? Yes. Is the weather fit? Yes. Are you busy? No. So why not go to the beach? "There might be a good reason, but I don't know what it is".

`Arrays` implements 98% of what is required. I remain at "I don't think there is a good reason'.